# how to bind list of dynamic boxes from VF page to controller, values are not binding when using action function with Immediate=true property

Tags: visualforce, controller, apexactionfunction

I have a requirement to capture list of names using Dynamic boxes on VF page. I am using action function for this, but behavior is getting changed based on attribute "Immediate" of action function. if Immediate="true" values are not binding to list showing blanks. if "false" its binding values correctly. But i have to use this with Immediate=true.

Below is my code:
Controller:

```
public with sharing class DynamicTextbox {

    public list<AUser> lstuser{get;set;} 

    public DynamicTextbox(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
         lstuser = new list<Auser>();
         lstuser.add(new Auser(''));
    }

    public void AddName() { 
        lstuser.add(new Auser(''));
    }    

    public class Auser{    
        public string name{get;set;}    
        public Auser(string name){
            this.name=name;    
        }
    }
 }
```

VF page:

```
<apex:page standardController="account" extensions="DynamicTextbox"> 
    <apex:form> 
        <apex:actionFunction id="AddAuthorizedUser" name="AddName" action="{!AddName}" reRender="Outpanel" immediate="false"/>
     <apex:outputPanel id="Outpanel" > 
         <apex:repeat value="{!lstuser}" Var="Auser" id="samrr"> 
            <apex:inputtext value="{!Auser.name}" styleClass="form-control"/>
      </apex:repeat>
      <button type="button" onclick="AddName();">&nbsp;<B>+</b>&nbsp;</button> 
        </apex:outputPanel> 
    </apex:form> 
</apex:page>
```

Comment: i don't see where/how you're using this action function - is this actionfunction just linked to the button?

Comment: @ronnie: Action function should trigger on button click.

Comment: <apex:page standardController="account"
           extensions="DynamicTextbox">
    <apex:form>
    <apex:actionFunction id="AddAuthorizedUser" name="AddName" action="{!AddName}" reRender="Outpanel" immediate="false"/>
    <apex:outputPanel id="Outpanel" >                  
            <apex:repeat value="{!lstuser}" Var="Auser" id="samrr">  
                 <apex:inputtext value="{!Auser.name}" styleClass="form-control"/></apex:repeat><button type="button" onclick="AddName();">&nbsp;<B>+</b>&nbsp;</button>
        </apex:outputPanel> 
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>

Comment: VF page code pasted in above comment.

Comment: Any reason why you "have to use this with Immediate = true".. this bit of code does not process any validations - only by your provided examples is adding an instance to the list - is the Apex code incomplete?

Comment: @Ronnie: this is not complete code, but i have other form validations. I don't need those validations to trigger when a new box is getting added on button click.

Comment: but they shouldn't be triggering since this is simply a wrapper that you are adding an instance of - not like you are performing any DML on this. Or are you doing this on a complete version here? a complete version would be much easier to go through - as it is - i see no reason why you should not be able to add a new instance to your list here. and no reason without DML being performed that you'd need to do with immediate = true.

Comment: @Ronnie: I have some form validations, means required fields  on form level. Eg: <apex:inputfield value="{Account.name}" required=true>. So don't want to trigger those on my button click, so i am using Immediate=true.

Comment: why not put those in an action region and keep those processing when you refresh the page - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_actionRegion.htm - here is a good link for a resource on that - you can use that and manage those sections of your layout. will save a lot of extra work long term. you can get better control of your pages behavior working with some of these things.

Comment: @Ronnie: Its not working if we have any form validations. if we have any input field with required=true on VF page, its not working.        <apex:inputfield value="{!Account.name}" required="true"/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use an action region - you can not need to process these validations that are required when adding a new row here like so:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="DynamicTextBox"> 

    <apex:form id="form"> 
        <apex:pageBlock id="block" mode="mainDetail">
           <apex:pageblockSection columns="1">
                <apex:inputField value="{!Account.AccountNumber}" required="true"/>  
             </apex:pageBlockSection>
             <apex:outputPanel id="Outpanel" > 
                  <apex:actionRegion>             
                    <apex:repeat value="{!lstuser}" Var="Auser" id="samrr"> 
                        <apex:inputtext value="{!Auser.name}" styleClass="form-control"/>
                    </apex:repeat>
                    <apex:commandButton value="+" action="{!addName}" reRender="block"   />
                 </apex:actionRegion><br />
                 <apex:outputText value="List size: {!lstUser.size}" />
            </apex:outputPanel> 
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form> 

</apex:page>
```

try Changing your button from a Button to a commandButton and use rerender like this - reRendering the component that contains your other items will also work with actionRegion - i have noticed that the HTML 'button' tag will nullify this behavior and you will get default processing of the form instead. I added a litte output text here in my testing that just shows my list count - but this is tested and DOES work

Comment: its not working if we have any form validations.      if we add a input field with required='true' to the VF page its not working.         <apex:inputfield value="{!Account.name}" required="true"/>

Comment: so check in the save method that Name is populated before saving - if not - return and display the error that name is required.  That would be the simple fix for that.

Comment: @user26702 I have updated my response with some tested and verified code for your case. Doesnt have to be a page block containing the objects in your layout - just an outputpanel will work too - i just used that in my own testing.

Comment: Thank you so much @Ronnie. Solution working with action region and Command button.

Comment: Glad i could help. Good luck with the rest of your project.